# ember 1.0.0 linkTo does not work with nested resources transitionTo not working?

Tags: ember.js, nested, routes

I have nested resources (order items) and two outlets on one screen I render to.

If I click an object nothing happens. If I replace the linkTo with the href its the same problem.  When I hover over the link it is shown in the footer of the browser, but not when clicked in the adressbar. When I manually write it in the adressbar and reload the page it works. What am i doing wrong?

The page is served thru a simple sinatra server.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
        <!-- Included CSS Files (Compressed) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
                <h2>Welcome to MyEmberPlayGround.js</h2>
                <hr>
                {{outlet "left"}}
                -------------------
                {{outlet "right"}}
                </script>

                <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="orders">
                    <h2> list all orders</h2> 
                    {{#each order in controller}}
                    <!--
                    <a href="/#/orders/{{unbound order.id}}">{{order.name}}</a>
                    -->
                    {{#linkTo "order" order}}{{order.name}}{{/linkTo}}
                    {{/each}}
                </script>


                <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="order">
                    <h2> say Hello from order </h2>
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here the app.coffee

```
##setting up global scope to namespace root
root = exports ? this
root.debug = true


App = Ember.Application.create
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true 
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
  LOG_BINDINGS: true

#####
##Generate nested  Data 
##Without serverconnect

  #####

App.Order = Ember.Object.extend()
App.Item  = Ember.Object.extend()

App.orders = Em.A()
App.items  = Em.A()

App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"1", "name":"o1_item1"))
App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"2", "name":"o1_item2"))
App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"3", "name":"o1_item3"))

App.orders.pushObject(App.Order.create("id" : "1" , "name":"Object1", "items":App.items)) 

App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"1", "name":"o2_item1"))
App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"2", "name":"o2_item2"))
App.items.pushObject(App.Item.create("id":"3", "name":"o2_item3"))
App.orders.pushObject(App.Order.create("id" :"2" , "name":"Object2", "items" : App.items)) 


App.Router.map -> 
        @route 'orders', path:  '/'
        @resource 'orders' , ->
             @resource 'order', {path: ':order_id'}


App.OrdersIndexRoute = App.OrdersRoute = Ember.Route.extend
   #model: -> App.Order.findAll()
   model: ->  App.orders
   setupController: (controller, model) ->
       controller.set('content', model)

   renderTemplate: ->
          @.render("orders",{outlet: "left", into: "application"})


App.OrderIndexRoute = App.OrderRoute=Em.Route.extend
      model:(params) ->
          console.log params
          App.orders[params.order_id]
      renderTemplate: ->
          @.render("order",{outlet: "right", into: "application"})
```

Thank for any help or hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links will work when you have visited the route orders. In order to achieve this you can modify your routes and use an IndexRoute to transition. The code is provided in plain js and coffee ,

JS

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('orders', {
    path: '/orders'
  });
  return this.resource('orders', function() {
    return this.resource('order', {
      path: ':order_id'
    });
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo("orders");
  }
});
```

coffee

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "orders",
    path: "/orders"

  @resource "orders", ->
    @resource "order",
      path: ":order_id"



App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(redirect: ->
  @transitionTo "orders"
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59jgj/3/

You may have noticed, since you tried visiting the url by reloading the page, that the orders outlet disappears when you link-to the order.
If you want both to be visible you may try to rearrange your templates i.e. include the order outlet in your orders outlet.

http://jsfiddle.net/59jgj/4/

Comment: Thanks for that solution . This works great and is the best information about routing I have got. Unfortunatelly there is so much disinformation around in the net. Do you know some good resources for the thinking behind the routing ? The emberdoc is not so good to understand this.